# How do capacitive screens work with rubber head stylus?

Tags: capacitive, touchscreen

Now I kind off know that Capacitive Screens have like capacitors built into them that create an electrostatic field. Now whenever a thing that can carry charge or a conductor touches it distorts the field. Then the processor somehow calculates the location of touch

The thing is when I use a battery and try to use it as a stylus the -ve side does register touches but not the +ve side. Can anyone tell me why this happens? 
Edit : Got the Answer It was cause there was not good amount of surface in contact.

Is this the same reason that when I connect a wire to the cell and try using it to distort the field but it doesn't sense it?

And how do these rubber tipped stylus work? They are not conductors right?

I know there are many similar questions out there but I didn't find any of them helpful. Any articles or anything will be helpful.

Comment: Capacitive touch does not work like you explain, look up on Wikipedia how it works. Your question has a lot of **wrong** assumptions. Do research first, then ask.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I updated the Answer.

Comment: You can get conductive rubber.  It doesn't have to be a good conductor to work.

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't detect the positive side because it it too small, the negative end has a larger area.